# Angular 2(4) - Trigger a function only on first time focus

Tags: javascript, angular

I'd like to know if there is a way to execute a function on focusing the element BUT only on the first focus of the lifecycle of the component, and none there after.

For example, this code should only trigger after the first focus and only 
then:

`(focus.firstTime?)="someFunc()"`

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks,

Comment: Create `boolean variable` which will be set on focus and in your function set `if` which will check that variable

Comment: If you work on inputs in a managed form, you could use pristine: the input is only pristine when the user hasn't interacted with it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@ViewChild('foo', {read: ElementRef})
foo: ElementRef;


Observable.fromEvent(this.foo.nativeElement,'focus').first()
.subscribe(()=> this.someFunc());
```